# Node ImageMagick resize doesn't preserve file name

Tags: node.js, image-processing, imagemagick, docpad, node-imagemagick

A lot of solutions are pointing toward's using mogrify, which would work great if it was part of the Node js implementation. All I need to do is resize my images and retain the file names, but place them in a separate "resized" folder. Here's what I'm doing here (in coffeescript, as a plugin for DocPad static website generator):

```
# Export Plugin
module.exports = (BasePlugin) ->

  im = require 'imagemagick'

  # Define Plugin
  class ImageMagickPlugin extends BasePlugin

      # Plugin name
      name: 'imagemagick'

      im.resize
        srcPath: './src/files/images/source/*.jpg'
        dstPath: "./src/files/images/resized/.jpg"
        width: 256
      , (err, stdout, stderr) ->
        throw err  if err
        console.log "resized some files to fit within 256"
```

The result is that my images are resized properly, and placed in the correct folder, but the names themselves are "-0.jpg, -1.jpg, -2.jpg", and so on. I'm really writing this for our own specific use, rather than a serious plugin for DocPad, though I think when it's working well we can definitely modify it for general use.

I appreciate any help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code like this :

```
# Export Plugin
module.exports = (BasePlugin) ->

  im = require('imagemagick')

  # Define Plugin
  class ImageMagickPlugin extends BasePlugin
    # Plugin name
      name: 'imagemagick'
      config:
        source: "images"
        suffix: "_resized"
        width: 256

      writeAfter: (opts,next) ->
        docpad = @docpad
        config = @config
        docpad.getDatabase().forEach (document) ->
          attr =  document.attributes
          if attr.extension is 'jpg' and attr.relativeDirPath is config.source
            srcPath = './src/files/' + attr.relativePath
            dstPath = './out/' + config.source + "/" + attr.basename + config.suffix + ".jpg"
            im.resize
              srcPath: srcPath
              dstPath: dstPath
              width: config.width
            , (err, stdout, stderr) ->
              throw err  if err
              console.log "File resized: " + attr.filename
        next()
```

This way, you loop over the files looking for jpg files in ./src/files/images/ and you write the resized version directly in the ./out/images/ with a modified name : foo.jpg is resized in foo_resized.jpg. By doing this, you don't "pollute" your src files.

If you just want to replace the source images by the resized ones in ./out/images/, you can simply define an empty string for the suffix in `docpad.coffee`:

```
plugins:
  imagemagick:
    suffix: ""
    width: 300
```

or just set it in the config object of the plugin!

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much Dharma! I should have a moment tonight to test this out. Will mark this as complete post testing :)

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your simple and tidy solution!